# Using XMLHttpRequest in IE9/10

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I've got a js solution that quite heavily relies on ActiveXObject that I need to transfer to "standard XML". I've found a few interesting things, for example if I do a XMLHttpRequest in IE10 there is no xml-part of the responseXML (responseXML.xml) as it is in IE9.

So I used the XMLHttpRequest.responseText and parsed that with the DOMParser, now if I use getElementsByTagName on that document the result is different from when I use it on the responseXML.xml, both in output and type. From the responseXML.xml I get a string out and from the parsed responseText I still have an XML document. The output is different by what nodes I get out, the responseText-version have a node less somehow.

Is there anywhere these things are documented. The code I have that I need to change is quite creative with checks of the type "node.firstnode.childnodes[i].lastnode.childnodes.length" so it's sort of important I know what I get from the getElementsByTagName on the different types.

Edit** Sorry, had a ResponseXML where it should have been a XMLHttpRequest. The ResponseXML above is a XMLHttpRequest.ResponseXML just to be clear.

Comment: use `jQuery.ajax()` instead

Comment: what does `responseXML.responseXML` property give you?

Comment: responseXML.responseXML is not defined, neither is responseXML.xml.

Comment: I just checked in IE10 and got the expected result with `<xhrobject>.responseXML` (see http://jsfiddle.net/UVRvM/). I hope the server is sending correct content-type header.

Comment: Thanks Salman, I think it does on my part too, however it's different from IE9 which this was coded for so I would like to make as little change as possible considering this is 2000 rows of js that I haven't done myself.